# Doing Data transfer from Finacle to sql server database through SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I am doing data transfer from Finacle db to my sql server db by usingh SSIS.
I am in bank and we use finacle for data storage.now under my project i have to transfer only customer and account information..But as the data is huge,it is taking too much time...

for examople:I started my query for data fetch from finacle on 18th for 3 regions and it got completed on 19th .Then I have run that same query on 19th for another 3 regions.This way we are proceeding:::::

last we will run the query to upload all the new accounts and customer data from our first day.

**My problem is:I do not want duplicate data....i.e as i am uploading data from server again and again,it will led to duplicacy... is there any way i can put a check that if data is already there in my destination table- dont put it again and if it is not there ,then only put it.Please help me in this.**

Comment: I see that you've used the `mysql` tag. Is Finacle a database on mysql? Is your target database on mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Import your data to a staging table on SQL Server.   Then run a stored procedure that copies only the data that doesn't exist in the destination table from the staging table to the destination table.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this previously and did a little research. I happened to find this really simple workable solution here:
https://finaclestack.com/questions/how-to-prevent-data-duplication-when-running-an-import-from-tabley-to-tablex-in-finacle/

It says:

**1.** If the tableY content is not much, then just select * from tableY, fetch ‘insert statement’ of the result and run the statement in tableX.

**2.** If the tableY content is much, then select in batches using a where clause. Then fetch ‘insert statement’ of each result and run the statement in tableX.